# Finding Records in a Radius postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am not sure what wrong with below query:

```
SELECT id,  earth_distance(ll_to_earth( 41.273147, -75.896858 ), 
ll_to_earth(business_address_latitude, business_address_longitude)) as distance_from_current_location FROM events 
WHERE earth_box( ll_to_earth(41.273147, -75.896858), 20000.00) @> ll_to_earth(business_address_latitude, business_address_longitude);
```

as trying to search the records in the radius of 20000 but as i checked the result it give me the records which is more then 20000 mtr distance like 24286 meter distance.
I am not sure whats wrong at the above query.
Any suggestion plz.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong, you're just using the box instead of circle so it's normal. [The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/earthdistance.html) states clearly:

> Some points in this box are further than the specified great circle
>   distance from the location, so a second check using earth_distance
>   should be included in the query.

So just select the points that have distance <=20000 in the an outer query.

Comment: so if i am checking only with eath_distance then also it will be fine?

Comment: @Dev it will work but it won't use an index so it'll be slower.